# Android Push - Third party server can't log in Google GCM to be whitelisted

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to test the new Android GCM API.

In the client side, everything goes good. The application can register and unregister itself properly.

In the third party server I have issues. I am testing it using the Python example server that Google provides but it can't authorize the connection with Google GCM because the project is not whitelisted. I have tried to whitelist it through [this website](https://services.google.com/fb/forms/gcm/) but it always returns a 500 error.

Also, I don't want to use upstream messaging at this moment but just send messages from the server to the devices. Do I still need to be whitelisted? In that case, is there any other Google resource to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to whitelist your Google API project if you are not using user notifications or Cloud Connection Server. The Python example is for Cloud Connection Server, and you don't need it for simply sending messages from your server to your app. Use the simpler HTTP API.

You can read [here](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/http.html) about GCM HTTP Connection Server.

Comment: So it can not be xmpp ?

Comment: @Jorge XMPP requires to signup in that form and wait to be whitelisted.